# No consigo establecer un height: 100% en mi aplicación de React

Tags: css, modal, height

Hola que tal me ocurre lo siguiente, tengo una aplicación en React que genera notas de recordatorio para apuntar cosas, código etc..
Cuando haces click en estas notas, se despliega un modal, el cual independientemente de donde esté la pantalla (si en el top, en el bottom, etc...) el modal siempre debe ir en el centro de la pantalla.

Esto ocurre si hago click en notas que están situadas entre 0 - 100vh del height, pero si por ejemplo hay más notas, que eso causa que haya un scroll hacia abajo, y hago click en las notas, el modal solo ocupa **los primeros** 100vh de la pantalla por así decirlo.

He probado a usar en mi contenedor del modal `position absolute`, con `top,left,right,bottom a 0`, y nada, ocurre igual, también he probado a establecer `height 100%`, y más de lo mismo. El modal solo ocupa los primeros 100vh.

Se os ocurre algo? Este es mi código css actualmente

```
const styles = {
    wrapper:{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100vh',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        zIndex: 2
    },
    window:{
        borderRadius: 5,
        position: 'relative',
        background: 'repeating-linear-gradient(#f1ede9, #f1ede9 31px, #94acd4 31px, #94acd4 32px)',
        padding: 15,
        boxShadow: '2px 2px 10px black',
        zIndex: 4,
        width:620,
        height: 600,
    },
    closeBtn:{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        cursor: 'pointer'
    },
    background:{
        width: '100%',
        minHeight: '100vh',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        background: '#000',
        opacity: 0.4,
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: 3
    }
}
```

Y esta la estructura

```
<Portal>
        {active && (
            <div style={styles.wrapper}>
                <div style={styles.window} className="wobble-horizontal-top">
                    <button style={styles.closeBtn} onClick={toggle}>X</button>
                    <div>{children}</div>
                </div>
                <div onClick={toggle} style={styles.background}/>
            </div>
        )}
      </Portal>
```

Contexto en imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Corregido simplemente cambiando el wrapper de `position: absolute` a `position: fixed` y añadiendo `bottom: 0` `right:0`